How to strip the numeric part in this file name?
How to strip the file name is file name is test-5.2.3-25-patch and we only want to strip the numeric numbers 5.2.3-25 in this file
A regular expression to only strip file name
file_name="test-5.2.3-25-patch"

Use grep with the -oP options to extract the numeric part?
numeric_part=$(echo "$file_name" | grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+-\d+')


Define the file path
file_path="/opt/dev/test_123"
Extract the filename from the file path
file_name=$(basename "$file_path")
Strip the part after the underscore
stripped_part="${file_name#*_}"
Print or use the variable
echo "Stripped part: $stripped_part

What does the comment mean, is that part of the question? Can you update the question with the expected output(s) ?

sed -E 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+//' <<< $file_name?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

./test.sh <<EOF
yes
yes
yes
EOF

@AdilMirza Please check if my edit of your question is ok and correct if not, it's hard to read. With "strip" you mean remove or extract? Best to edit your question and clarify...
